# Use of _ENV in Lua function does not have effect

Tags: lua

I'm reviewing some toy examples from Lua and I found the following one over there with respect to environments:

```lua
M = {}         -- the module
complex = {} -- global complex numbers registry
mt = {} --metatable for complex numbers
   function new (r, i)
       local cp = {}
        cp = {r=r, i=i}
        return setmetatable(cp,mt)
      end
      M.new = new        -- add 'new' to the module
    function M.op (...)
    --Why does not it work?
    local _ENV = complex
        return ...
      end  
      function M.add (c1, c2)
        return new(c1.r + c2.r, c1.i + c2.i)
      end
      function M.tostring (c)
        return string.format("(%g,%g)", c.r, c.i) --to avoid +-
      end
    mt.__tostring = M.tostring
    mt.__add = M.add
```

```lua
complex.a = M.new(4,3)
complex.b = N.new(6,2)
--nil
M.op(a+b)
--It works
M,op(complex.a+complex.b)
```

The use of `_ENV` has no effect. However, if I use `complex = _G`, both lines work. How do set a local environment for `M.op`. I'm not asking for specific libraries, I just want to know why it does not work and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

> M.op(a+b)

This line doesn't do what you expect, because it uses values of `a` and `b` that are available when this method is called. It doesn't matter that you set `_ENV` value inside the method, as by the time the control gets there, the values referenced by `a` and `b` have already been retrieved and since both values are `nil` in your code, you probably get "attempt to perform arithmetic on global..." error.

> how to fix it.

I'm not sure what exactly you want to fix, as you already reference the example that works. If you assign `complex.a` you can't assume that `a` will have the same value without mapping `complex` table to `_ENV`.